# Using Vector map in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

So I have a vectorised map that I would like to control using leaflet.

Say I have `map.eps` or `map.pdf`, how would I go about using this?

I'm very new to this. When I view the image I can zoom as much as I want and it scales due to it being a Vector?

From what I can see Leaflet uses `.png` or `.jpg`.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> Say I have map.eps or map.pdf, how would I go about using this?

You would not - you would take your EPS or PDF file and convert it into an raster image. If you need high resolution, a high-resolution raster image. EPS and PDF, great formats they kind of are, are not image formats that are supported on the web.